# A general guideline approach to solving programming exercises?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, coding-style

Ok so there are a million questions on how to solve this and how to solve that problem, but I can't find a good resource on SO on how to actually go about solving programming problems in general. Like first break the problem down to simple pieces and attack each piece individually or whatever blah blah. I know if you look at great programmers they all follow a certain path in solving problems and if you compare each of those great programmers approach you can see a lot of places where their approaches cross. So for all the new comers and programmers what is the best step by step approach(guideline) in solving a typical programming problem?

Comment: http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/

Comment: http://www.howtoprogram.it/

Comment: Considering the myriad of domains in which computer applications are used, I doubt that you can come up with a step by step guide for everything. The one you mention, I think, is the only one which really holds. Breaking things into smaller pieces depends on the experience and knowledge of the given person. Different people with different backgrounds will most likely break the same novel problem into different chunks.

Comment: For a typical programming problem I use the concept of map and reduce.

Comment: @npinti I agree with you and thats why I put it in my comment, but I think there is too much emphasis on language then there is on actual problem solving approach on SO. Too many programmers take a long time in solving a basic problem because they do not know a good structured approach. They just start somewhere and hope to by revision to solve the problem. This applies to new programmers. Experienced programmers have a structured approach, a simple guideline per say on approaching that simple problem. Take an essay for example if you know how to create an outline writing the essay is easier

Comment: @TheMadKoder: StackOverflow deals in particular with implementation problems. Asking your question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ might provide better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is academically abstract, meaning it can't be answered the way to provide you with valuable guidelines to approach an actual programming problem.

Imagine that you have a toolbox and you ask how to use it for an abstract task. What would you expect as an answer? That's pretty much the question you asked.

Nevertheless, there are a few guidelines on which tool to select for each type of task and how to operate them in general.

Firstly, you have to pick technology (the tool) to use on your task. There are a few types of programs and you have to understand which one is you're working on. You have to consider your budget, time-to-market and other restrictions.

For instance, if you're working on a web application, you have a few tools to choose from. Drill, driver, impact driver, impact wrench... Oh those are from the handyman's toolbox... You have a different toolbox, in which you have Java stack, Microsoft stack, Ruby on Rails, PHP and other more exotic technology stacks. Depending on the task and your personal experience or resource availability you make your decision.

When you have your technology, you can dive deeper (read instruction on the tools you're about to use). In IT world instructions would be books or other similar resources. Particularly, in order to properly design a Java or C++/C# application, you'd want to get familiar with basic design patterns.
On the other hand, if you're using Ruby on Rails those patterns would do no good for you.

Last but not least is to learn how to organize the work on your project. How to divide one big project into smaller tasks, how to track progress and ensure it's done well and on time. It makes you a project manager in addition to your programming skills.

There are a few popular ways to manage an IT project (not only IT actually). Most trendy is so called Agile Methodology. It's basically a set of guidelines. You pick and choose what works for your project and your team out of them.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you already familiar with programming stuff, these are the steps that come to my mind:

- Consider the problem as a whole in the first glance. Try to understand the expected input and output clearly and the overall idea in general.
- As you already mentioned, it is important to break the problem down into meaningful pieces of works/logics which are going to "talk" to each other. If you take the previous step seriously, it can help you a lot on this
- After selecting each piece of work, start thinking about an idea to solve that little part. Don't limit your mind in available tools that you are already familiar with. Just think of the idea. There are many tools/packages/etc that you don't know about them which after completing your idea can be found over the web and surprise you!
- As already said, do not limit yourself but just consider the nature of the programming language that you are going to use. Sometimes, you might face some limitations there...

Answer (score 0):

Use the Feynman Problem-Solving Algorithm:

1. Write down the problem
2. Think very hard
3. Write down the answer

The first step is the most important one. The essence of step one is that in order to solve a problem you must first understand it. You don't have to write it down. If you find writing boring, you can instead describe your problem to someone (a [co-worker](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CardboardProgrammer) or even a [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)). Most problems can be solved this way.

If step 1 fails, you need to resort to step 2. If you find thinking hard too difficult, there is an alternative. Since you have completed step 1 you now know the problem. So you also know what keywords to provide to google. With good google charma you should get some good hits, probably on stackoverflow. If not, you can either ask a new question on stackoverflow or actually think hard and solve the problem yuorself.

Step 3. Pretty straightforward. You understand the problem. You have figured out a solution. All that remains is to write, test and document the code. Shouldn't be too hard, just another day of bread-andbutter programming.